# Return res and next in a custom express function

Tags: node.js, function, return

How do I return both `res` and `next` in an express function:

```js
const customfunction = async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
   // how do I set cookie and return next()?
   return res.cookie('someToken', someToken, {
     signed: true,
     // etc...
     }
   );
  return next();
 } catch (err) {
   // catch here, for example, return res.status(401).clearCookie...
 }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to, neither `res.cookie` nor `next` actually needs to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An express request handler (like something you pass to `app.get()` or `router.post()` or something like that) does not pay any attention to the return value from that handler.

So, `return` inside such a handler is used only for flow control to stop further execution of the function.

In addition, your code has two return statements one after the other:

```
return res.cookie(...);
return next();
```

Which makes no sense because the `return next()` line of code will never be executed as the function has already returned on the line before.

If this is middleware and you intend for some other request handler to still have a chance to process this request, then you would want something like this:

```
const customfunction = async (req, res, next) => {
    res.cookie('someToken', someToken);
    next();
};
```

It doesn't appear that there's any reason for the `try/catch` because neither of these should throw an exception (assuming your code doesn't have a syntax error in it).

But, if you really wanted the `try/catch`, you could do this:

```
const customfunction = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.cookie('someToken', someToken);
        next();
    } catch(e) {
        // make sure logs can see that this unexpected error is happening
        console.log("customFunction error", e);
        res.clearCookie('someToken');
        res.status(500).send("Internal Error");   // probably want a more glamorous error page
    }
};
```